# Vim opening terminal with different profile than the default

Tags: vim

I 'm working on MacOS Catalina and I am using vim 8.2

The only profile set up in my `iterm2` is the `Default` one.

[image]

which has been set up to used a slightly customized solarized theme as depicted below

[image]

I am now opening vim (which has also been set up to use its counterpart solarized [colorscheme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized))

[image]

My question is, why when I am opening the `:terminal` in vim, this opens in black background (I don't think there even exists a profile with such setting)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen when you have Vim running with `'termguicolors'` on. (You can confirm it and see where it's being enabled with `:verb set tgc?`.) Same as when running in a GUI (not the terminal), it will tell Vim to use 24-bit colors, and use the color scheme full RGB color specifications, rather than use the terminal color palette.

In that situations, Vim's colors get completely detached from those of the terminal where Vim is running, so Vim's built-in terminal no longer has access to the actual terminal colors.

You can set specific colors to use in Vim's built-in terminal with the `g:terminal_ansi_colors` variable (see `:help g:terminal_ansi_colors` for details.)

Alternatively, disabling `'termguicolors'` should work as well. Assuming the Vim color scheme has been built in a way that will use the terminal color scheme to reproduce the same colors, it might not have other side effects in how Vim colors otherwise look.

Answer (score 0):

Removing line

> set termguicolors

from .vimrc fixed it